# How jaxb inject values during unmarshalling process

Tags: java, jaxb

Does anybody know what jaxb uses to inject xml values into objects?
I have tried to put a breakpoint on the setters but it doesn't seem to take care of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JAXB (JSR-222) implementations will access public fields and properties (get/set) method pairs.  This access is normally done via reflection (but isn't required to be).  It could also be done via something like byte code generated accessors.

You can change it to access fields directly using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

Comment: And is it possible that it still work when my fields are private??

Comment: @Truman - Yes it will still work when the fields are private.  I will post a reflection example when I'm back in front of an IDE.  There are probably questions about private variables and reflection on Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So at he end there isn't a simple way to intercept the setting process of jaxb, is it so?

Comment: I want to modify my object before jaxb set it. Something like: public void setXXX(Object xxxx) { this.xxxx = xxxx+1; }

Comment: @Truman - If you don't want to do it on a mapped setter you could do it with an `XmlAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB apparently uses direct field access by default, but you can make it use Setter methods via the [`@XmlAccessorType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) annotation.

Read this blog post for more info:
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: I've seen that annotation is used on getters. On the opposite I want to modify my object before setting it. Something like:    public void setXXX(Object xxxx) {
  this.xxxx = xxxx+1;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Jaxb at some point uses reflections, which suprised me when I tried to use it in uncertified applet (restrictions on java sandbox in browser).

But I am sure it used setters in my case. I did some processing in setters(setting other internal variable at the same time) and it worked.